# How can you get the CSS pixel / device pixel ratio?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I want to find the ratio between CSS pixels and device pixels.

**Edit**: I should have realized that this is just zoom level. I've [added an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers/5078596#5078596) to the canonical reference on zoom levels.

CSS pixels are the unit we use for almost everything--it's what element.style.width, element.clientWidth, element.offsetWidth etc. mean. Device pixels are the pixels that the browser actually paints to. A few properties are measured in device pixels, e.g. window.screen.width, which is the screen size (e.g. 1024) that doesn't change when the user zooms in.

Motivation: when the user zooms in, I want to increase a canvas's width and height (while keeping style.width and style.height the same CSS pixel value), scale() the context, and redraw on a crisper upscaled canvas.

I've read [Quirksmode's A Tale of Two Viewports](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports.html) and [High DPI on Surfin' Safari](http://www.webkit.org/blog/55/high-dpi-web-sites/), but neither of them say how to get the ratio. The only ideas I have so far are to collect mousemoves and measure change in event.clientX divided by change in event.screenX, or to programatically create media queries using `moz--min-device-pixel-ratio`, use `getComputedStyle()` to test whether the rule matched, and narrow it down with a binary search. I hope there's a easier/more reliable way.

**Edit**: I've tried using the `@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:1)` queries with Chrome, Safari, and Firefox 4, and apparently Webkit treats the property as a constant device pixel to **screen pixel** ratio (which doesn't change with zoom), whereas Firefox 4 treats it as device pixel to **CSS pixel** ratio (which increases when you zoom in). So in Firefox 4, I can discover the CSS pixel / device pixel ratio using a binary search, but not with Webkit.

Comment: whilst flash dependent, you might find this informative: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5024493/browser-viewport-size-in-device-pixels/

Comment: This is a good question but several years old now.  One of the answers mentions FF29 and we are now at 53.  Can you choose the best answer and offer some update as to the status of this information, time permitting? :-)

Answer (score 72):

You can use `window.devicePixelRatio` in Webkit based browsers to get the device pixel ratio directly in JavaScript. I have used this on Google Chrome, Android browsers (2.2+) and Mobile Safari. I have no idea about other browsers though.

Comment: `window.devicePixelRatio` works in Opera (Presto 2.8+) http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/presto28/#changes

Comment: window.devicePixelRatio === 1 in Kindle Fire HD 7", even though it has a pixel density of 150%...

Comment: Firefox (as of v.29) still incorrectly calculates `window.devicePixelRatio` if the user has zoomed their window.  Firefox renders the page at the device's pixel ratio (example: 2.0 for "Retina" type displays), but then returns the actual calculated pixel ratio (ex: at 3x window zoom, the devicePixelRatio would return 2.0*3 = 6.0).  This causes mayhem for `canvas` elements.

Comment: As of Firefox 18 Mozilla alters the devicePixelRatio value when the browser is zoomed so 'device..' is deceptive.

Answer (score 25):

You can always use the following method and it would work in all the browsers

```
window.getDevicePixelRatio = function () {
    var ratio = 1;
    // To account for zoom, change to use deviceXDPI instead of systemXDPI
    if (window.screen.systemXDPI !== undefined && window.screen.logicalXDPI       !== undefined && window.screen.systemXDPI > window.screen.logicalXDPI) {
        // Only allow for values > 1
        ratio = window.screen.systemXDPI / window.screen.logicalXDPI;
    }
    else if (window.devicePixelRatio !== undefined) {
        ratio = window.devicePixelRatio;
    }
    return ratio;
};
```

Comment: Great, works on FF, Chrome, IE, Edge even with zoom factors! Also tested on iOS 10.

Answer (score 3):

There is a much better CSS/JS solution:

```
/** sample media query for pixel-ratio=2" **/
@media  
(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), 
(min-resolution: 192dpi) { 
  .pixel-ratio-holder:before {
   content: "2";
  }
}


function jsPixelRatio(){
   return window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.pixel-ratio-holder'), 'before').getPropertyValue('content').replace(/[^a-z]/g,'') * 1;
}
```

Comment: Good trick. Should be noted it doesn't (seem to) work before document.ready().

Answer (score 0):

### How to get device Pixel Ratio

This example uses `window.devicePixelRatio` as a starting point **AND** also `window.matchMedia()` Web API as a fallback calculation.

The browser support for both those features is pretty good, so this should work great for most of use cases.

Here is a function that retrieves this information, [originally written by PatrickJS and published as a GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/gdi2290/7772743):

```
function getDevicePixelRatio() {
    var mediaQuery;
    var is_firefox = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1;

    if (window.devicePixelRatio !== undefined && !is_firefox) {
        return window.devicePixelRatio;
    } else if (window.matchMedia) {
        mediaQuery = "(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),\
          (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),\
          (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2),\
          (min-resolution: 1.5dppx)";
        if (window.matchMedia(mediaQuery).matches) {
            return 1.5;
        }
        mediaQuery = "(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),\
          (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2),\
          (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1),\
          (min-resolution: 2dppx)";
        if (window.matchMedia(mediaQuery).matches) {
            return 2;
        }
        mediaQuery = "(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0.75),\
          (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 0.75),\
          (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/4),\
          (min-resolution: 0.75dppx)";
        if (window.matchMedia(mediaQuery).matches) {
            return 0.7;
        }
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

**CanIUse**: [`window.devicePixelRatio`](https://caniuse.com/#search=devicePixelRatio), [`Window.matchMedia()`](https://caniuse.com/#search=matchMedia)

**Useful links**: [MDN - `window.devicePixelRatio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio), [MDN - `Window.matchMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia)

Comment: In the future, when you adapt code or content from another source, please be sure that you [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) it appropriately. You had the link here, but you buried it at the bottom under the heading "source", instead of including it directly with the copied code. Also, you need to include the name of the original author. I've made the changes for you here; please keep this in mind going forward. Thank you!