# CSS 1px border in a Webview gives 2px border on some sides, when devicePixelRatio = 1.5

Tags: android, html, css, android-webview, border

I'm loading a page in a Android app with a `WebView` (=embedded browser in app), with standard settings:

```
mywebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
...
mywebView.loadUrl("http://example.com/test");
```

Everything works correctly except the following minor issue:

**Problem: The 1-pixel-wide border is not displayed correctly: one or two of the four sides of the border are 2px instead of 1px.** It looks like this:

[image]

- I noticed that `window.devicePixelRatio = 1.5` on my device
- Here is the HTML code (I don't use a code snippet, because they are not runnable on mobile devices anyway):

  ```
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <style type="text/css">
  #test { display: inline-block; border: 1px solid #c4c4c4; padding: 9px; }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <a id="test">Test</a>
  </body>
  </html>
  ```
- The solutions given in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13415412/1422096) (I have put a bounty there, so I already tested the answers) don't work: `border: 0.5px solid black;` or `border: 0.75px solid black;` show **no border at all**, so this is not a duplicate. This is a specific question when `devicePixelRatio = 1.5` (it behaves different than `1` or `2`)
- [Live demo here](http://gget.it/yw0ujzo8/index.html), **I cannot reproduce the problem** in Chrome for Android, but only in a Android app using `WebView` and displaying the same page (strange, isn't `WebView` using the same rendering engine as Chrome?)

Answer (score 1):

I just have a similar problem and it is fixed, I do not if this solution will help you or not:

It helped by give a margin to the div

```
.brand .col-8 {
    padding-right:0;
    margin-right:-1px;
}
.brand .col-4 {
    border-left:1px solid #d8d8d8;
}
```