# How to get current CSS media parameter values?

Tags: jquery, css, media-queries

I'm trying to debug media queries with Chrome Developer Tools by editing the `@media` line in style panel. But this is too labour intensive.

What I'm looking for is:

- width/device-width in pixels/millimeters/other units
- font size in millimeters

Is there a way to run a jQuery command or some other tool to get these values?

Any search on debugging media queries finds suggestions on one particular page or handycraft debugging (edit this, see that, etc.), or trivial stuff like `$('body').width()`.

Comment: Can you give an example of the info you're trying to find, exactly? It's unclear what you mean.

Comment: @TylerH Edited it a bit

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer your question, but Firefox has a neat [responsive design mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Responsive_Design_View) (Ctrl-Shift-M) which tells you your exact viewport dimensions and lets your resize either by mouse or by keyboard. I've found it amazingly useful for working with media query breakpoints.

Comment: @Jeremy yes, I used the same in Chrome, but still the cycle is a bit dragging: edit > refresh > drag > think what the value might be > edit.

Comment: @culebrón fair enough; you can edit the breakpoint in Firefox's style-sheet editor (but not the DOM inspector) which could cut out some refresh cycles, I guess. Probably works the same in Chrome.

Answer (score -1):

You can always get the width and height (with JavaScript) from the body and calculate with these pixel values.

Like (jQuery ):

```
var screenWidth = $('body').width();
```

Here is a demo, this might help you.
http://codepen.io/gabrieleromanato/pen/CuviB

And a similar entry i think: [How can you get the CSS pixel / device pixel ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063489/how-can-you-get-the-css-pixel-device-pixel-ratio)

Comment: I don't need width and height, it's too trivial to ask a question here.

Comment: And what is with the demo?

Comment: That seems to have assumed that the physical size of a pixel will *always be the same* and has hardcoded that ratio into the code … since the question is about determining what the ratio is for whatever device runs the code, it seems to be remarkably unhelpful.

Comment: `millimeters.width = Math.floor(width * 0.264583);` From W3C docs, pixels don't convert into milimeters this straight way. They are device-dependent, not constants.

Comment: Thats true. I wouldnt recommend to use this for all devices too. But in certain situations where you dont need to get it working on every device, its enough. @culebrón

Comment: @Webworx23 that's exactly what I'm trying to do. There are thousands of mobile phones with different screen sizes. I'm trying to at least see what values I have and when a query starts working.

Comment: And here you find a big list of devices, maybe also usefull. http://pieroxy.net/blog/2012/10/18/media_features_of_the_most_common_devices.html. So thats it from my side.

Comment: Thanks! Surprizingly, none of my test phones are on the list. :) e.g. Samsung Galaxy G530H, LG P698.